# Collection View Cells not appearing in Collection View?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I created a Collection View using purely the storyboard interface builder. This is what the storyboard looks like:

[image: Storyboard]

My collection view's properties are default as well. I haven't written anything into my `ViewController.swift` yet.

[image: Collection View]

For some reason, when I run on my phone / emulator, none of the buttons are showing.

Comment: What is there in simulator? Did you give delegate and datasource ?

Comment: ***I haven't written anything into my `ViewController.swift` yet.*** You should [see tutorial](https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=uicollectionview%20tutorial%20swift&oq=collectionview%20t&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.6238j0j1) first.

Comment: I really don't think that a collection view is what you want looking at your app. You have a static, fixed number of elements (calculator buttons). I'd recommend taking a look at [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview)

Comment: probably it will show its appearance after properly set `data-source` and `delegate` and this happens also with `tableView`, did you ever realize ?.

Comment: @BhavinRamani Ah sorry, I got confused between UICollectionView and UITableView. Just starting to learn what I found to be a very intriguing language.

Comment: @think123 check my ans, hope this helps you sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just configure the `collectionView` properly see below code and image:

Implement the `delegate` methods of `collectionView`:

```
class yourClassController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: 
    UICollectionView!) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, 
    numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return yourArray.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, 
cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> 
     UICollectionViewCell! {

     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollectionViewCell

     // Configure the cell
     cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
     cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.section):\(indexPath.row)"
     cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "circle")



    return cell
}
```

Then from your `storyboard` set the `delegate` and `datasource` by drag and drop see image:

[image]

**Note:** `collectionView` appears when you do complete above formality with its relevant class.

Answer (score 4):

UICollectionView does not support static cells like UITableView. You will have to set its dataSource,delegate and configure your cells in code.