# didSelectItemAt: not being called (UICollectionView)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` in a `UIView` class because it's implemented in an other class.I set the `delegate` and `dataSource` and `allowsSelection` to true but `didSelectItemAt` method doesn't work and I can't figure out why.This is the code:

```
class NewRecipeViewCategoryCV: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.allowsSelection = true
    return cv
}()

let newRecipeModel = NewRecipeModel()

let cellId = "cellId"

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    collectionView.register(NewRecipeViewCategory.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor).isActive = true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return newRecipeModel.recipeCategory.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! NewRecipeViewCategory

    cell.categoryText.text = newRecipeModel.recipeCategory[indexPath.item].uppercased()

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(123)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let category: UILabel = {
        let category = UILabel()
        category.text = "BREAKFAST"
        category.font = UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Regular", size: 13)
        category.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        category.textColor = UIColor.black
        category.sizeToFit()
        return category
    }()
    return CGSize(width: category.frame.width+15, height: category.frame.height+12)  
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

Comment: But is your collectionView being loaded with the dataSource?

Comment: There may be delegate and datasource not connected properly [have a look this ans sure help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39917452/4003548).

Comment: Thank you,solved.